# Function Object Internal Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

It is said every javascipt object have internal prototype property,then predefined Function object also have the internal prototype property.So which object prototype does its internal prototype called **proto**  points to?

```
function Object(){}
alert(Object.constructor)//function Function(){[native code]}
```

so i m referring to the internal prototype of the function Function(){} object not its prototype property . like Function object instance have their internal prototype pointing to Function object.prototype likewise Function object internal prototype point to what?not taking about the prototype property that gets added to it.I know what will the internal prototype of the prototype object points to.

Comment: Can you show a code example of what object you're referring to?

Comment: @rekire why dont it have the sence??Function object also have the internal prototype property

Comment: Why do you keep asking this question?

Comment: @MaizerePathak, please have someone assist you with your English, it is difficult to understand you. Rephrasing your question would be helpful.

Comment: All your questions seem to be about prototypes and functions... if you don't understand the answers to your previous questions, please comment on them and ask for clarification instead of asking a slightly modified version of the same question.

Comment: @FelixKling haha good joke

Comment: It's not a joke. 5 out of 6 of your questions are about prototypes.

Comment: @FelixKling plz see my edited question for once .

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript:function prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559798/javascriptfunction-prototype)

Comment: @David just to know if it has what will it poits to since there is no object left now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects inherit from `Object.prototype`, but they may inherit from other prototypes as well depending on the type of object. Functions inherit from `Function.prototype` (which inherits from `Object.prototype`).

Comment: @MaizerePathak, `Function` is a function, so it inherits from `Function.prototype`.

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript, functions are just a specific type of object. Thus a function's prototype is the same thing as an object's prototype. For more reading on functions as objects, check out [this link](http://helephant.com/2008/08/19/functions-are-first-class-objects-in-javascript/).